# how to extract data with days ago and get specific time in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, data-extraction

> i want to extract data from facebook marketplace using selenium , i want to get the date of the products for the past 2 days (ads listed 2 days ) then from the past n weeks ( ads listed n weeks ) starting from today , I think i can get it by thd function (find_elements_by...) but I don't know how to use it , thank you in adavance [this prod for exemple
> `Date = find_elements_byName('value').text  Date_prod = Current_Time - Date`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOBC1.jpg)

Comment: You need to post a minimal reproducible example, - show us your code, what have you tried until now?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus each product from facebook has a time posted for exemple (2 days ago) I want To extract the time of this products Starting from today for exemple ( vehicles listed on 26 september 2022 >>> 26 - 2 = 24 september 2022 the day was the product listed ) how i can get the exact by the time ago